# Typescript knockoutjs data-binding not working

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

Trying to get the knockoutjs (2.21) introduction tutorial working with typescript (0.9).  Data-binding doesn't appear to work.  This is the first javascript I have looked at in years.  I think I am missing how to properly connect the html to the viewmodel as generated by using typescript classes.  Problems only occurred once I tried to introduce the class to the tutorial.  Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javelinBCD/9nnnJ/).

HTML fragment:

```
<body>
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>

<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName">Go Caps</button>
</body>
```

typescript fragment

```
class koIntroductionViewModel {
    firstName: any;
    lastName: any;
    fullName: any;

    constructor() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
        this.fullName = ko.computed(this.createFullname());
    }

    createFullname() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    capitalizeLastName() {
        var currentVal = this.lastName;
        this.lastName = currentVal.toUpperCase();
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    ko.applyBindings(new koIntroductionViewModel());
}
```

Generated javascript

```
var koIntroductionViewModel = (function () {
    function koIntroductionViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
        this.fullName = ko.computed(this.createFullname());
    }
    koIntroductionViewModel.prototype.createFullname = function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };

    koIntroductionViewModel.prototype.capitalizeLastName = function () {
        var currentVal = this.lastName;
        this.lastName = currentVal.toUpperCase();
    };
    return koIntroductionViewModel;
})();

window.onload = function () {
    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new koIntroductionViewModel());
};
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work

Comment: Sorry I should have said the data-binding wasn't working  in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript code should be more like this:

```
var koIntroductionViewModel = (function () {
    function koIntroductionViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
        this.fullName = ko.computed(this.createFullname, this); // 1
    }
    koIntroductionViewModel.prototype.createFullname = function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(); // 2
    };

    koIntroductionViewModel.prototype.capitalizeLastName = function () {
        var currentVal = this.lastName(); // 2
        this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase()); // 3
    };
    return koIntroductionViewModel;
})();
```

1. You shouldn't be calling the `createFullname()` function, here, you are trying to pass the function to the computed observable, not its return value.  Also, if you're going to use `this` in a computed function, you must pass in the owner as well.  By declaring the computed as:

   ```
   ko.computed(this.createFullname, this);
   ```

   That way, you're saying that if `this` is used in the `createFullname()` function, that `this` should refer to the `this` in the current context.
2. Observables are functions.  You must call it to read the value it holds.
3. To store a value in an observable, you must call the observable passing in the value to store as an argument.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/Gq6gj/)

---

The corresponding typescript would be:

```
class koIntroductionViewModel {
    firstName: any;
    lastName: any;
    fullName: any;

    constructor() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
        this.fullName = ko.computed(this.createFullname, this);
    }

    createFullname() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }

    capitalizeLastName() {
        var currentVal = this.lastName();
        this.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of these work, thanks for the explanation.  I was close to getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

Give this modified fiddle a shot..

http://jsfiddle.net/9nnnJ/5/

```
var koIntroductionViewModel = (function () {
    var self = this;
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });


    this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
        var currentVal = self.lastName();
        self.lastName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
    };

});


var model = new koIntroductionViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```